# Custom view for related list

Tags: salesforce, customization

I'm a bit new to SalesForce development, i've been given a small list of changes to make and most i've done but I want to go the extra mile on one if possible.

I want to know if it is possible to have a custom view (using a visual force page if necessary) for a related list.

We have a customised section under opportunities which shows items related to another group of items (in this case, rooms within a building and items within the room), they want a free text field (there's a description field already) displaying on a custom page layout.

Currently this is set to a related list and picks items from a table and shows them horizontally, however, now i've amended this list to show the description field it is starting to look a bit squashed.

Ideally i'd like the description on a second line so that each detail line has all the general details about a room (these items relate to products) on the first line and then the description on a second and then repeat for each set of item lines.

In something like PHP this would be very simple:

```
foreach ($data as $record) {
  echo $record->item_number . " : " . $record->item_name . " : " . $record->item_quantity ." : ". $record->item_extended_price . "<br>\n";
  echo $record->item_description . "<br>\n";
}
```

Is there a way to change the display setting so it points to a visual force page so I can use some markup to display the data or is there a simpler way to get a line-break when customising the related list view.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to customize the related list, you should **write your own related list with a VisualForce component**. Then, you can customize it an any way that you'd like.

Take a look at this [github repository](https://github.com/cloudspokes/generic-related-list) that contains the code from a [CloudSpokes contest](http://www.cloudspokes.com/challenges/1093) that relates to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think related lists are off limits as you're describing. You could create a VF page to implement the related list functionality and embed it as a section in the page layout. If you placed it toward the bottom it might seem more like a related list.

Comment: Thanks for the responses Sean and Jeremy, I was waiting to see if the community would up-vote one over the other.  I think both have merit and either approach would work.  I'm having so much trouble with VF stuff that i'd probably lean towards the component level personally.